# tuple index out of range for fft

Tags: python, audio

I'm new to coding so this is a little confusing to me. I was trying to make a convolution of a songbird audio I have but I'm getting this

```
error: tuple index out of range for Y = fft(y_sum, N) where y_sum = np.sum(signal,axis=0).
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

```
# initialization
fs = rate # sampling frequency, Hz
dt = 1/fs # sampling interval, seconds
T = round(len(signal)/(rate)) # duration, seconds
tv = np.linspace(0,T,T*fs+1) # time vector
# Convolve the Gaussian window with the added sine waves
fr1 = np.convolve(y_sum, gaussian, mode='same')
N= len(signal) # number of FFT points (length of signal)
fv = fftfreq(N, dt)[:N//2] # make the frequency vector

# Calculate the FFT of the complex convolved result
FR1 = fft(fr1,N)
# Calculate the FFT of the complete y signal
Y = fft(y_sum,N)
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you didn't show what is in `y_sum` but it seem it is `y_sum = np.sum(signal,axis=0)` and `sum(signal)` may have single value - or less value than `len(signal)` (`N`)